# golang - Unable to find directed multigraph package

Tags: data-structures, go, graph

I am unable to write a directed multigraph in golang. I see some code in callgraph but thats not a generic multigraph. Anybody aware of what package i can use? I tried looking at graph, but that does not have a multigraph module.

Thanks, Abhishek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you:
https://github.com/manav416/directed-multigraph

https://godoc.org/github.com/twmb/algoimpl/go/graph also has graph utilities